# How many ways are there to permute elements of the multiset {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} so that the first and last elements are different?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to permute elements of the multiset
{1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} so that the first and last elements are different?

I am not really sure how to do this so that the first and last elements are different. Ignoring the last statement, I know there are a total of 8!/(2!*2!), different permutations, but now that the order matters im not sure how this changes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** How many multisets  have $1$ at the first and the last position and how many multisets have $2$ at the first and the last position?

Comment: So for example if I fix the first and last position to 1, I can then find how many permutations of the remaining positions. Since there are 6 others the number of multisets of 1 at first and last position is (n-2)(n-3)(n-4)(n-5)(n-6)(n-7), and since n = 8, it is 6*5*4*3*2 multisets, similarly for fixing 2 as the first and last position. Then the total number of permutations such that the first and last number is different is 8!/(2!*2!) - 2(6*5*4*3*2)?

Comment: @StarLight: This is  the  right  way. Note, to also divide by $2!$ due to the other doubled item.